# pushd home dir, and not have it use tilde?

Tags: bash, cd-command, home

Using the `pushd` command in your home directory give you ~, but when I try to access it with
`cd $(dir +1)`, it gives an error `cd: ~: No such file or directory`, after some research, (please correct me if I'm wrong) I think the error is that ~ is not used at the start of line, and the ~ sign is not changed into `/home/myname`.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `dirs -l +1` to print the full path to the directory, with no `~` abbreviation. Tilde expansion only happens when it's typed explicitly, not in the output of a command.

```
cd $(dirs -l +1)
```

Alternatively, use zsh, where you can simply write

```
cd +1
```

But even in bash you can just write

```
pushd +1
```

which has almost the same effect (it leaves the stack in a different order).